# Using the values of a previous "row" in a pandas series

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, elementwise-operations

I have a CSV that looks like this (and when brought into a pandas Dataframe with
`read_csv()`, it looks the same).

[image]

I want to update the values in column *ad_requests* according to the following logic:

For a given row, if *ad_requests* has a value, leave it alone. Else, give it a value of **the previous row's value for *ad_requests* minus the previous row's value for *impressions***. So in the first example, we would like to end up with:

[image]

I get partially there:

```
df["ad_requests"] = [i if not pd.isnull(i) else ??? for i in df["ad_requests"]]
```

And this is where I get stuck. After the `else`, I want to "go back" and access the previous "row", though I know that this is not how pandas is meant to be used.
Another thing to note that is the rows will always be grouped in threes, by column *ad_tag_name*. If I `pd.groupby["ad_tag_name"]`, I can then turn this into a `list` and start slicing and indexing, but again, I think there must be a better way to do this in pandas (as there is many things).

Python: 2.7.10

Pandas: 0.18.0

Comment: Hint: `df.ad_requests.ffill() - df.impressions.cumsum().shift()` gets you partway there.

Comment: Interesting. Using this approach, values are *slightly* off though for the first few blank rows, then ultimately become negative: http://imgur.com/a/k7faf

Comment: That's why it's a hint and not a full solution.  The cumsum needs to be reset to 0 each time ad_requests is nonzero, or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None #suppresses "SettingWithCopyWarning"
for index, elem in enumerate(df['ad_requests']):
    if pd.isnull(elem):
        df['ad_requests'][index]=df['ad_requests'][index-1]-df['impressions'][index-1]
```

The warning comes from the fact that we're changing the values of a view of a dataframe, which affects the original dataframe. That is what we wish to do, however, so it doesn't really concern us.

(Python 2.7.12 and Pandas 0.19.0)

**EDIT:**

Changing the last line of code from

```
df['ad_requests'][index]=df['ad_requests'][index-1]-df['impressions'][index-1]
```

to

```
df.at[index,'ad_requests']=df.at[index-1,'ad_requests']-df.at[index-1,'impressions']
```

removes the need to suppress any warnings:

```
for index, elem in enumerate(df['ad_requests']):
    if pd.isnull(elem):
        df.at[index,'ad_requests']=df.at[index-1,'ad_requests']-df.at[index-1,'impressions']
```

Comment: I knew I needed to use the indexes of the previous elements somehow, but had forgotten about `enumerate()`. And I knew the final solution would be short and neat, as most pandas-based solutions are. Thank you for this elegant approach.