# Using values in the next row of a dataframe

Tags: python

I have timestamped data in a csv with a resolution of 10 minutes, [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VDkb.png). Each timestamp has an "id" which is either 1 or 0. I am trying to create a new column, "time", which returns 0 if "id" = 0, otherwise it should return the value of "time" in the next row plus 10. I am able to do this easily on Excel, and the formula I used is shown in the image.

I am trying to use Python to do the same thing. After importing the csv data as a dataframe using pandas, I had a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733560/using-the-values-of-a-previous-row-in-a-pandas-series) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323750/how-to-access-previous-next-element-while-for-looping). I copied the "id" column to a new column, "time" and used the following code, but the values of "time" remain exactly the same (1 or 0).

```
for i, e in enumerate(df['time']):
    if e==1:
        df.at[i,'time']=df.at[i+1,'time']+10
```

Based on the solution in the first link, I tried changing the value of '1' to null and using `if pd.isnull(e)`, but ended up getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`.

I attempted it again by ordering the rows in reverse, changing `i+1` to `i-1` but it didn't work either, and I was getting `KeyError: -1`.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this in Python?

**Edit:**

Apologies, I probably didn't explain my question well. I've figured out how to get the solution I wanted. I realised that the problem was due to the dtypes for "id" and "time" were both `object`. The `KeyError: -1` problem was solved by ordering the rows in reverse and assigning a value to "time" in the very first row if it doesn't equal 0. I'm going to ignore any row before the first row with "id" of 0, so I used 999999.

**Solution:**

```
#sort timestamp in reverse
df=df.sort_values(by="timestamp",ascending=False)

#change dtype object to int64
df['id']=df['id'].astype(np.int64)
df['time']=df['id']

#assigning value to "time" in first row
if df.loc[0,'time']==0:
    df.set_value(0,'time',0)
else:
    df.set_value(0,'time',999999)

#using the previous row's value to evaluate "time"
for i, e in enumerate(df['time']):
    if e==1:
        df.at[i,'time']=df.at[i-1,'time']+10

#sort timestamp back in ascending order
df=df.sort_values(by="timestamp")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, but you didn't specify how you want to handle `NaN` values which will happen in your question

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,0,0,1,0,1], 'nums':[10,20,50,10,10,30,20]})


   id  nums
0   1    10
1   1    20
2   0    50
3   0    10
4   1    10
5   0    30
6   1    20


df['nums'] = pd.concat([df, df['nums'].shift(-1)], axis=1).apply(lambda x: 0 if x['id'] == 0 else x[[2]]+10, axis=1)

   id  nums
0   1  30.0
1   1  60.0
2   0   0.0
3   0   0.0
4   1  40.0
5   0   0.0
6   1   NaN
```

You can just add a `fillna(0)` to the end of the one-liner if you want to fill the `NaN` values.

Comment: Hi Dmitry. Thanks for the suggestion. Apologies, I don't think I have explained my question well and this wasn't exactly what I was looking for. However, your solution did help me think about my method and allowed me to come up with a solution, which I have posted as an edit :)